# Axon framework: Aggregate identifier must be non-null after applying an event

Tags: java, axon

Using axon framework I've got error:

> Aggregate identifier must be non-null after applying an event. Make sure the aggregate identifier is initialized at the latest when handling the creation event.
>   I use this StorageEngine:

```
@Bean
public JdbcEventStorageEngine jdbcEventStorageEngine() throws Exception{
    return new JdbcEventStorageEngine(dataSource::getConnection, NoTransactionManager.INSTANCE);
}
```

Code fails when the message for aggregateId is recieved second time like in this handler:

```
@CommandHandler
public void handle(CreateProductCommand command) throws Exception {
    Aggregate<Product> productAggregate = null;
    try {
      productAggregate = repository.load(command.getId());
    } catch (AggregateNotFoundException exception) {
      logger.info("Aggregate with " + command.getId() + " is not found. Creating new one...");
      productAggregate = repository.newInstance(() -> new Product(command.getId()));
    }
    productAggregate.execute(product -> product.createProduct(command.getId()));
}
```

But if I use this it works fine:

```
@Bean
public EventStorageEngine eventStorageEngine() {
  return new InMemoryEventStorageEngine();
}
```

How I should configure eventStorageEngine for postgres/mysql database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing spring devtools worked out nicely.